# Use variables in json path expressions

Tags: karate

I have a feature file to retrieve the data from csv file for the given parameter. In order to do it, I need to use a variable in the JsonPath expression to retrieve data for given parameter. I tried may ways, but using variable in jsonPath is not working. I'm using 0.9.4 version

I tried the below ways:

```
 * def userId = get[0] testData[?(@.UserType=='${userType}')].UserId
     * def userId = get[0] testData[?(@.UserType==userType)].UserId
     * def userId = get[0] testData[?(@.UserType=='#(userType)')].UserId(I suppose this can only be used in json/xml)
```

Below hard coded value works fine:

```
 * def userId = get[0] testData[?(@.UserType=='SuperAdmin')].UserId
```

Called feature:

Feature: Utility to extract the various types of data from excel datasource

Background:

```
 * def DataUtility = Java.type('com.org.utils.DataUtility')
 * def dataUtils = new DataUtility()
     * def testData = read('classpath:testdata/TestData.csv')
```

Scenario: Retrieve userId for a given user type

```
      * def userId = get[0] testData[?(@.UserType=='${userType}')].UserId
```

Calling feature:

```
 * table params
 |   userType   |
 | 'SuperAdmin' | 

     * def extractedData = call read('DataExtractor.feature') params
     * def userID = extractedData[0].userId
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried using variables in Json Path.
Example:

```
String elementPath = "$.[" + i + "].item.value";
```

In this statement, i is a loop variable. After this pass it to the `read` api of `DocumentContext`.
It has worked perfectly fine for me.
I am using JsonPath & DocumentContext from jayway to achieve this.

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
```

Comment: this is not an answer. the question was for [karate] here you are talking java